# Perl And Sqlite

Tags: perl, sqlite

Can someone tell me how to access a sqlite3 database from perl.

the code

```
use DBI;
use DBD::SQLite;

my $dbh = DBI->connect(
  "dbi:SQLite:dbname=/cbilldata/media/database/collector.db","",""
) or die "Cannot connect: $DBI::errstr";
```

returns error

> DBI connect('dbname=/cbilldata/media/database/collector.db','',...) failed: database disk image is malformed at ./db.pl line 7
>   Cannot connect: database disk image is malformed at ./db.pl line 7.

Comment: It sounds like the database file is corrupted.  Is there a backup?

Comment: Can you open the database with the sqlite3 command line tool?

Comment: You don't need to `use` the `DBD::SQLite` module.  It is the `DBI` module's job to load that module if it is needed (hence the SQLite part of the dsn).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either your version of DBD::SQLite is a *very* old one that uses SQLite 2 and not 3, or the message is accurate and your database is corrupt.

Comment: Thanx hobbs,i had an old version of DBD::SQlite